# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed fom Postman

Tags: python, django, rest, frameworks, postman

I am trying to create a simple model with foreign keys using Django rest framework.
This are the models:

```
class Route(models.Model):
    place_origin = models.ForeignKey(
    Place, null=False, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
```

This are the serializers for each model:

```
class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ["id", "name"]

class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    place_origin = PlaceSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ["id", "place_origin"]
```

This RouteSerializer has the place_origin property in order to show the place details(all the fields from it) when I am looking at the route detail. What I mean is for routes I want to display:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "place_origin": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "New york"
        }
    },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "place_origin": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Boston"
        }
    }
]
```

And not just:

```
[
    {
    "id": 1,
    "place_origin": 1
    },
   {
    "id": 2,
    "place_origin": 2
    }
]
```

This is the view:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def routes_new_route_view(request):
    """
    Create a new route
    """
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        place_origin = Place.objects.get(id=data["place_origin"])
        data["place_origin"] = PlaceSerializer(place_origin)
        data["place_origin"] = data["place_origin"].data
        serializer = RouteSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        else:

        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I want to send the request from postman this way:

```
{
    "place_origin": 3
}
```

But I am getting the error from the title.
Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you're trying to send data via a PlaceSerializer but this field is read_only. On the other hand, your DB expects place_origin since you precised null=False in your model. Both combined gives the error "Not NULL constraint failed".

The easiest way is to slightly modify your serializer in order to have one field for write and another for read.

```py
class RouteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    place_origin = PlaceSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    place = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(source="place_origin",queryset=Place.objects.all(),write_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ["id", "place_origin", "place"]
```

Here, you will use place field as a way to create the relationship with your Route instance.

Comment: I would have to add that field to the model too?

Comment: No, the `source` arg tells the serializer what field to search. So it looks to create a relationship with place_origin when sending {"place":1}. Updated my answer with a few more precision from where your error is coming from.